How to use updated Credentials in get requests using python requests library
I am accessing an API that has a limited time bearer token auth process
to get the bearer token i need to query a specific URL every hour to get the new token.
I have the code for this and it works correctly.
The problem i have is that when i update the .env file with the new token and then send the get request it uses the old token to try gain access and i constantly get error code 401.
i load my tokens using the python-dotenv library.
I have my code set up such that if i get a 401 error, it updates the auth token then tries again.
when i was testing i found that even though the token is updated the following request still use the older token.
i expected my code to encounter the 401 error then get the new token, retry with the new token and succeed.
I have tried running the new token in a curl command to make sure it was correct and it works. I also noticed that if i close my VScode then reopen it after getting the new token the code works as expect  till i need a new token.
I need to run this code every 10 min for 16 hours, so closing the VScode or restarting the lambda server to get the code running again every hour is not a viable solution

Hello, could you please provide a Minimal Reproducible example: . At least include code so we can try figure out what is going on.

It is just a guess but maybe you (re)use a session object with an outdated token?

from your explanation you update the .env file, which is only read once (when you call load_dotenv()). What you need to do is, when you get an updated key, update the corresponding variable in your code, not the .env file.

After going through different methodes I found online, I found that adding the override property to the load_dotenv() like this load_dotenv(override=True) resolved my issue.
